# Proof $\vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r})'=0\iff ||\vec{r}||=K,$ with $K \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus

I need to proof the following property:

Let $r: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth vectorial function, then

> $\vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r})'=0\iff ||\vec{r}||=K,$ with $K 
>  \in \mathbb{R}$.

I could prove the $\leftarrow$ direction, but i could not with the right direction.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $r \cdot r: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable since $r: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth. Differentiating
$$
(r \cdot r)'=r' \cdot r+r \cdot r'=2(r \cdot r')=2 \cdot 0=0.
$$
Hence $r \cdot r=k$ where $k \geq 0$ is a constant. Then
$$
||r||=\sqrt{r \cdot r}=\sqrt{k}.
$$
Let $K=\sqrt{k}$ and $||r||=K$.